# Change css class when hovering html element

Tags: javascript, css

I have a loop of divs with a class `item`. When mouseover on an element, `active-item` class is added via javascript:

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>

<!--on mouseover-->
<div class="item active-item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

When `item active-item` class appears, I want to add `opacity: 0` to `item` class, and to add `opacity :1` to `item active-item`.  I need to do it without `:hover`, because that its expand card and when mouse will leave item, it will be `opacity:0`.

Comment: Have you considered using `:hover` in CSS?

Comment: usually, "active" is applicable only with mouse click, but who knows what your use case is. Anyways, it would help if you post the mouseover js event you've made.

Comment: this question has been answered multiple times already, please check google

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Its expandable cards. If mouse it's not over item, it will have the same 0 opacity. So thats not a solution for me...

Comment: Ahmed, I tried lot of answers and do not works for me, that why I'm posting. Please propose solution, these empty content from you doesnt helps.

Comment: Also I have complicated JS, Php, Css, thats why I posting demo content, not an actual markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use JS for this task

```css
.itemcontainer:hover .item:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="itemcontainer">
  <div class="item">1
  </div>
  <div class="item">2
  </div>
  <div class="item">3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to handle ```.active``` case?

Comment: there is no need to add an extra class on hover. the .active case is actually the :hover case

Comment: You are right! Thanks for answer, helped me a lot!! Have a great day/evening!

Answer (score 0):

So, if you already have the Js part that adds the active class, then you can do this:

```
.item {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item.active {
  opcaity: 1;
}
```

But if you want to avoid Js at all you can do that:

```
.item {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item:hover {
  opcaity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That will make all the items disappear at the start. The logic is- on start there is loop of divs with class=item with opacity=1.  After when you mouseover on one of the "item", js adds class "item-active". When I will have "item-active" on one of the divs, I will be need to make opacity of all others = 0, and "item-active" 1.

Comment: Then you should go with Fabrizio's choice @StenStmith